# Breaking up a list into elements

Tags: python, list, grouping, element

Having troubles breaking up and regrouping my list so that information about a single airline company and it's fees are in one list element, by a loop, with every 6 elements becoming an element on its own.

```
myList = ['Southwest', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Yes!', 'JetBlue', '20', '35', '75', '125', 'Yikes']
```

(This list goes on for 6 airlines in total, there's 2 listed here, the list is in order of Airline name, fees(4), and then a short word describing the value)

I need to group `Southwest, 0, 0, 0, 0, Yes!` together as an element.

Then group `JetBlue, 20, 35, 75, 125, Yikes` together as an element.

Then I will do this for 4 more airlines. I obviously want to use a loop since it's multiple airlines.

Comment: Length of a segement is 5 so: `[myList[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(myList), 5)]` would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for every number of elements inside `myList`

```
def chunks(myList):
    return [ ', '.join(myList[i:i+6]) for i in range(0, len(myList)-1, 6) ]

myList = ['Southwest', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'Yes!', 'JetBlue', '20', '35', '75', '125', 'Yikes']
print(chunks(myList))
```